# Decode a JSON array

Tags: arrays, swift, codable

I'm just learning the Swift Decodable protocol and am running into a problem. I am able to decode one json object into a swift object, but am stuck with decoding an array.

What goes well:

imagine following json:

```
let json = """
{
  "all" : {
    "_id": "59951d5ef2db18002031693c",
    "text": "America’s cats, including housecats that adventure outdoors and feral cats, kill between 1.3 billion and 4.0 billion birds in a year.",
    "type": "cat",
    "user": {
      "_id": "5a9ac18c7478810ea6c06381",
      "name": {
        "first": "Alex",
        "last": "Wohlbruck"
      }
    },
    "upvotes": 4,
    "userUpvoted": null
  }
}
"""

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
```

I can decode it to a Fact object with following code:

```
enum Type: String, Decodable {
    case cat = "cat"
}

struct Fact {
    let id: String
    let text: String
    let type: Type
    let upvotes: Int

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case all
    }

    enum FactKeys: CodingKey {
        case _id, text, type, upvotes
    }
}

extension Fact: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let allContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: FactKeys.self, forKey: .all)
        id = try allContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: ._id)
        text = try allContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        type = try allContainer.decode(Type.self, forKey: .type)
        upvotes = try allContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .upvotes)
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let fact = try decoder.decode(Fact.self, from: jsonData!)
```

But the api is giving me an array of objects:

```
let json = """
{
  "all": [
    {
      "_id": "59951d5ef2db18002031693c",
      "text": "America’s cats, including housecats that adventure outdoors and feral cats, kill between 1.3 billion and 4.0 billion birds in a year.",
      "type": "cat",
      "user": {
        "_id": "5a9ac18c7478810ea6c06381",
        "name": {
          "first": "Alex",
          "last": "Wohlbruck"
        }
      },
      "upvotes": 4,
      "userUpvoted": null
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b01a447c6914f0014cc9a30",
      "text": "The special sensory organ called the Jacobson's organ allows a cat to have 14 times the sense of smell of a human. It consists of two fluid-filled sacs that connect to the cat's nasal cavity and is located on the roof of their mouth behind their teeth.",
      "type": "cat",
      "user": {
        "_id": "5a9ac18c7478810ea6c06381",
        "name": {
          "first": "Alex",
          "last": "Wohlbruck"
        }
      },
      "upvotes": 4,
      "userUpvoted": null
    }
  ]
}
"""

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
```

And I want to store that in an allFacts array that hold my Fact objects

```
class Facts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allFacts = [Fact]()
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let allFacts = try decoder.decode([Fact].self, from: jsonData!)
```

I'm using the same extension on my Fact struct. But it's giving me an error and I am totally lost for a second. Any idea how I can solve this ?
Do I need to create codingKeys for the class as well ?

```
Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not to mess around with nested containers. This is less efficient than the default stuff. In your case you would have to use `nestedUnkeyedContainer` and iterate the array which is still more expensive.

Instead just add a **root** struct

```
let json = """
{
  "all": [
    {
      "_id": "59951d5ef2db18002031693c",
      "text": "America’s cats, including housecats that adventure outdoors and feral cats, kill between 1.3 billion and 4.0 billion birds in a year.",
      "type": "cat",
      "user": {
        "_id": "5a9ac18c7478810ea6c06381",
        "name": {
          "first": "Alex",
          "last": "Wohlbruck"
        }
      },
      "upvotes": 4,
      "userUpvoted": null
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b01a447c6914f0014cc9a30",
      "text": "The special sensory organ called the Jacobson's organ allows a cat to have 14 times the sense of smell of a human. It consists of two fluid-filled sacs that connect to the cat's nasal cavity and is located on the roof of their mouth behind their teeth.",
      "type": "cat",
      "user": {
        "_id": "5a9ac18c7478810ea6c06381",
        "name": {
          "first": "Alex",
          "last": "Wohlbruck"
        }
      },
      "upvotes": 4,
      "userUpvoted": null
    }
  ]
}
"""

let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)

enum Type: String, Decodable {
    case cat
}

struct Root : Decodable {
    let all : [Fact]
}

struct Fact : Decodable {
    let id: String
    let text: String
    let type: Type
    let upvotes: Int

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id", text, type, upvotes
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)

print(root.all)
```

Comment: Another question, how do I change the Root struct to an ObservebleObject class with a @Published var all ?

Comment: That's indeed another question and more related to the Combine framework which I'm not familiar with.